# Erlang lists:filter/2 cannot use comma instead of andalso

Tags: erlang

Following code gives me warning at compile time:
Warning: use of operator '>' has no effect

```
rd(a,{x,y}),
List = [#a{x=1,y=2}, #a{x=3,y=4}],
lists:filter(
    fun(E) ->
        E#a.x > 1, E#a.y =:= 2
    end, List).
```

But when I substitute comma with andalso, there is no warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using comma in this case only separates two actions, without effect to each other: `E#a.x > 1` and the next operation (which is result of function) `E#a.y =:= 2`

It means that in your case, filter function is equal to:

```
fun( E ) ->
   E#a.y =:= 2
end
```

Only if you're writing **guard expressions** usage of comma is equal to usage of `andalso`, otherwise - comma just a **separator** between actions.

So, you may rewrite your function in two ways:

1)

```
fun
(E) when E#a.x > 1, E#a.y =:= 2 ->
   true;
(_Othervise) ->
   false
end
```

2)

```
 fun( E ) ->
    (E#a.x > 1) andalso (E#a.y =:= 2)
 end
```

Comment: Yes, in the body `,` just separates actions and gives them an order to be evaluated. The compiler is telling you that `E#a.x > 2` has no side effects, will never generate an exception and its return value is ignored so it will never affect execution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is as @stemm has said.

In the body `,` just separates actions and gives them an order to be evaluated. The compiler is telling you that as `E#a.x > 2` has no side effects, will never generate an exception and its return value is ignored then it will never affect execution.

In a guard, however, `,` separates *guard tests* which all have to succeed for the the guard to succeed.

Be careful about viewing guards as normal expressions they do behave differently, as here for example. Guards also behave differently on errors. So while guards *look* like expressions they are really tests.